# Flash message not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get flash messaging to work in Laravel 5.2. Everything seems to be correct but when I go to /alert nothing happens. Any suggestions?

The following is my routes.php..

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
  Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
    'as' => 'welcome',
    ]);

  Route::get('/alert', function()
  {
    return redirect()->route('welcome')->with('info', 'You have signed up!');
  });
});
```

The following is my alerts.blade.php...

```
 @if (Session::has('info'))
<div class="alert">
     {{ Session::get('info') }}
</div>
@endif
```

The following is my master.blade.php..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>@yield('title')</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
   @include('includes.header')
   <div class="container">
     @yield('content')
     @include('includes.alerts')
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use as the documentation suggest instead of using the facade \Session

From [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data):

> Of course, after the user is redirected to a new page, you may retrieve and display the flashed message from the session. For example, using Blade syntax:

```
@if (session('info'))
<div class="alert">
    {{ session('info') }}
</div>
@endif
```

Your code work fine on my laravel 5.2 using the syntax above.

EDIT:

they use `return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');`

they don't use the method `redirect()->route()`

try to use this instead:

```
Route::get('/alert', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->flash('info', 'You have signed up!');
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
});
```

Comment: I changed my code just as yours is but still nothing still displays on the page.

Comment: I updated my code, note that I had `session('status')` not `session('info')`

Comment: Yes I understood what you meant. I keep my code at session('info') but to no avail

Comment: When I tried your last suggestion, I got an error...                                                             FatalErrorException in routes.php line 23:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::flash()

Comment: Sorry yeah i already updated that. My mistake I was missing the method session in the line `$request->session()->flash` try again and let me know with the fixed line

Comment: Now I got...   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::session()

Comment: Okay You are using the wrong request class namespace you need to use `\Illuminate\Http\Request` instead. on the function parameters. Updated the answer again.

Comment: not gettng the error no more but nothing displays on the page. This is what I have in my routes file....                  Route::get('/alert', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
      {
         $request->session('info','You have signed up!');
         return redirect()->route('welcome');
      });

Comment: You are missing the flash method: `$request->session()->flash('info', 'You have signed up!');`

Comment: I fixed the code but nothing happens when I go to http://laravel.testsite.com/alert

Comment: Doesnt it redirect you to welcome page? if you can, [enter here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110035/discussion-between-david-lavieri-and-slillz)

Comment: I resolved the problem. I had to remove my routes from Middleware. Com e to find out with the new update routes dont need to be inside there.